# how to convert excel sheet 3 as pdf file(It has to ask file name before save)

Tags: vba, pdf, excel

I am using Input template and I want to save Sheet 3 as PDF file with different name(before saving file system has to ask Path and file name). Here I created some code please help out of this problem.

```
Sub Mac()
Dim wsh As Worksheet, vWshs, DossierEvaluationkit

vWshs = Array("Dossier Evaluation Template")
With ActiveWorkbook
    For Each DossierEvaluationkit In vWshs
        .Worksheets(DossierEvaluationkit).ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:= _
            "C:\Users\s0900993\Desktop\Lateral DEK" & LateralDossierEvaluationkit, Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
            IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=False
    Next DossierEvaluationkit
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: where have you define your `LateralDossierEvaluationkit` variable?

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Please describe what is working and what is not, any error messages etc. Otherwise it's very hard to help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's good to use [`Application.GetSaveAsFileName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff195734.aspx) for cases such as these.

```
Sub GetSaveAsFilename()

Dim fileName As String

fileName = Application.GetSaveAsFilename(InitialFileName:="", _
                                         FileFilter:="PDF Files (*.pdf), *.pdf", _
                                         Title:="Select Path and FileName to save")

    If fileName <> "False" Then

        With ActiveWorkbook

                .Worksheets("Dossier Evaluation Template").ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, fileName:= _
                    fileName, Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
                    IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=False

        End With

    End If
End Sub
```